# Xml syntax error with literal ampersand & character

Tags: c#, xml

I have method in order to replace xml

`Replace` method:

```
public string EscapeXMLValue(string xmlString)
{
            if (xmlString == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlString");

            return xmlString.Replace("&amp;", "&");
}
```

This is my code and I get an exception:

I have xml and try to parse after that I want to use `.LoadXml`

```
  XML = EscapeXMLValue(XML); // Parse &amp; here

  xmlDoc.LoadXml(XML); // I get error here
```

XML:

```
<Vehicle>HB ICON 1.5 DCI 90 S&amp;S</Vehicle>
```

Error:

> An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 22503, position 40.

If I replace `&amp;` with `&`, it works, however if I replace `&` with `&amp;` it displays exception.

How can I solve the problem for `&amp;`? How can I remove it or do anything?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code - your post is *really* hard to read. It would also be much easier to help you if you would provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to manually escape your XML? If it has `&amp;` in it, is it not already escaped? Why are you replacing `&amp;` with `"`? There's nothing wrong with XML you showed us. Are you sure that's where the error is?

Comment: JonSkeet hope you understand me now thanks. JLRishe &amp; does not work inside xml file in my side where i miss here error is &amp; is not it ?

Comment: Generally, if you're processing XML as strings, you're *doing it wrong* (TM). There's an entire [Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) full of classes designed to work with XML. Don't ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-formed XML can't contain an unescaped `&` character except as part of an entity reference. When you replace `&amp;` by `&`, you achieve nothing other than making your XML ill-formed. So surely the simple answer is, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve the problem for &?

Put it into a [CDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlcdatasection.aspx) section to inform the Xml compiler that it is treated as a literal

```
 <Vehicle><![CDATA[HB ICON 1.5 DCI 90 S&amp;S]]></Vehicle>
```

Comment: @Soner it is unclear whether in the process  you can simply load the xml then change the node or try to change the node(s) in the raw text. One way is significantly easier than the other. I would load the xml raw into an `XDocument`, then parse each elements inner text to replace the `&` with `&amp` and then place into a CDATA section.